# How do I set two mutually exclusive check boxes in Jquery?

Tags: jquery-selectors

```
$(document).ready(function() {
            $("input:txtAge1").click(function(event) {
                if ($(txtAge1).attr("checked") == true) {
                    $(txtAge2).attr("checked", "unchecked");
                    $(txtAge2).attr("checked") == false)
                } 

                if ($(txtAge2).attr("checked") == true) {
                    $(txtAge1).attr("checked", "unchecked");
                    $(txtAge1).attr("checked") == false)
                }
            });
});



<input type="checkbox" id="txtAge1" name="option1" value=""/>21<br>
<input type="checkbox" id="txtAge2" name="option2" value=""/>55<br>
```

I am trying to select either one checkbox or the other. So if one box is UNchecked, it should either be not allowed or force the
other box to BE checked ...in other words, enforce either one or the other but never allow
a "undefined" condition

Answer (score 4):

Maybe I'm dumbing down the issue a bit, but why not try using radio buttons?

You can set one to be `selected` to avoid the user submitting an empty value.

Update: Since your customer wants checkboxes, here's a solution in jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   $('.radioButton').click(function() {
      $('.radioButton').prop("checked", false);
      $(this).prop("checked", true);
   });
});
```

That's the jQuery code. You should set your input boxes up like this:

```
<input type="checkbox" id="txtAge1" class="radioButton" name="option1" value=""/>21
<input type="checkbox" id="txtAge2" class="radioButton" name="option2" value=""/>55
```

That should work, but it's untested. I might've missed something.

Comment: Well, I have proposed that but the customer did want to see check boxes. I just thought it should be a easy fix.

Comment: Chuck...this is closer since it DOES keep each box checked once checked. But then it does not allow the exclusive "check one or the other" since they both remain checked.

Comment: I had missed a period above on line 3 to signify it being a class. Try the code now.

Comment: use  prop() instead of attr()

Answer (score 2):

One solution is to add two click events, one for each checkbox. When one is clicked, the other is unclicked.

```
$("#checkbox1").click(function() {
    $("#checkbox2").prop('checked', false);
});

$("#checkbox2").click(function() {
    $('#checkbox1').prop('checked', false);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I ran into this issue recently, except I needed checkboxes instead of radio buttons as having both options unchecked was a requirement.  I resolved it with something like this (adapted to the OP's code):

```
<input type="checkbox" id="txtAge1" />21
<input type="checkbox" id="txtAge2" />55

$(document).ready({
    $("#txtAge1").click(function() {
        if($("#txtAge1").is(':checked')) {
            $("#txtAge2").prop('checked', false);
        }
    });
    $("#txtAge2").click(function() {
        if($("#txtAge2").is(':checked')) {
            $("#txtAge1").prop('checked', false);
        }
    });
)};
```

Might not be that pretty, but it works.

Answer (score 0):

I also wanted to note the excellent link http://rndnext.blogspot.com/2009/08/mutually-exclusive-html-select-elements.html here.

One caution though, I used it to mutex two dynamically generated select lists inside a div. . Since the content to be manipulated is not available at page load, it was not working as expected. Following solutions at [jQuery - selecting dynamically created divs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10712051/jquery-selecting-dynamically-created-divs/10712086#comment19538965_10712086) helped resolve the issue.

Answer (score 0):

I would use this function. Allows mutual exclusion and allows uncheking:

```
$('#divId').find(':checkbox').click(function() {
         var state=$(this).prop("checked");
         $(':checkbox').prop("checked", false);
         $(this).prop("checked", state);
    });
```

Answer (score -1):

```
$("input[type=checkbox]").click(function () {
        $(this).siblings().prop("checked", false);
 })
```

Comment: Please add at least some explanation. Dumping just code in here is a quick way to get your post deleted.